# If Month=Particular month display content

Tags: php, conditional-tags, conditional-content

I want to use conditional tag to display content according to month. Such as if it is April, it should show something else something else. Right now I am using :

```
<?php if(is_month() == '2' ) : ?>

   <p>hello</p>

<?php else: ?>

   <p>Wow</p>

<?php endif ?>
```

The above doesn't work. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php if( "8" === date('n')):?>
  //what you want to show     

<?php endif;?>
```

Change '8' with the number of the month you want. More on the [date function.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Thnx. It works !!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `is_month()` is a conditional to check if the current page is a month based archive.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_month

To check the current date you need to compare your desired month with `date('n')`

This should be what you're looking for:

```
<?php if ( '2' == date('n') ) : ?>
     <p>It's February</p>
<?php else: ?>
     <p>Not February</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```